# sicp 5.3 garbage collection

Tags: garbage-collection, sicp

I am currently reading garbage collection realization at sicp and resulting code at the book have no sense for me.

```
begin-garbage-collection
  (assign free (const 0))
  (assign scan (const 0))
  (assign old (reg root))
  (assign relocate-continue (label reassign-root))
  (goto (label relocate-old-result-in-new))
reassign-root
  (assign root (reg new))
  (goto (label gc-loop))


gc-loop
  (test (op =) (reg scan) (reg free))
  (branch (label gc-flip))
  (assign old (op vector-ref) (reg new-cars) (reg scan))
  (assign relocate-continue (label update-car))
  (goto (label relocate-old-result-in-new))


update-car
  (perform (op vector-set!) (reg new-cars) (reg scan) (reg new))
  (assign old (op vector-ref) (reg new-cdrs) (reg scan))
  (assign relocate-continue (label update-cdr))
  (goto (label relocate-old-result-in-new))


update-cdr
  (perform (op vector-set!) (reg new-cdrs) (reg scan) (reg new))
  (assign scan (op +) (reg scan) (const 1))
  (goto (label gc-loop))


relocate-old-result-in-new
  (test (op pointer-to-pair?) (reg old))
  (branch (label pair))
  (assign new (reg old))
  (goto (reg relocate-continue))
pair
  (assign oldcr (op vector-ref) (reg the-cars) (reg old))
  (test (op broken-heart?) (reg oldcr))
  (branch (label already-moved))
  (assign new (reg free)) ;new location for pair
  ;; update free pointer
  (assign free (op +) (reg free) (const 1))
  ;; Copy the car and cdr to new memory. 
  (perform (op vector-set!) (reg new-cars) (reg new) (reg oldcr))
  (assign oldcr (op vector-ref) (reg the-cdrs) (reg old))
  (perform (op vector-set!) (reg new-cdrs) (reg new) (reg oldcr))
  ;; Construct the broken heart.
  (perform (op vector-set!) (reg the-cars) (reg old) (const broken-heart))
  (perform (op vector-set!) (reg the-cdrs) (reg old) (reg new))
  (goto (reg relocate-continue))
already-moved
  (assign new (op vector-ref) (reg the-cdrs) (reg old))
  (goto (reg relocate-continue))


gc-flip
  (assign temp (reg the-cdrs))
  (assign the-cdrs (reg new-cdrs))
  (assign new-cdrs (reg temp))
  (assign temp (reg the-cars))
  (assign the-cars (reg new-cars))
  (assign new-cars (reg temp))
```

First of all registers "free", "scan", "old", "new", "root" appears to be just indexes of values stored in "the-cars", "the-cdrs", "new-cars", "new-cdrs" for me.
The book says:
*The state of the garbage-collection process is controlled by maintaining two pointers: **free** and **scan**. These are initialized to point to the beginning of the new memory. The algorithm begins by relocating the pair pointed at by **root** to the beginning of the new memory.*

So assuming that **root** is not a pair leads us straight to **gc-loop** point without changing **free** and **scan** which ends program.
Assuming that **root** is a pair makes **new**=0, **free**=1, moves first element to the new memory and adjust old memory (which is only sane part for me), then it goes to **reassign-root** where **root**=0 (i see root as index of first element at the-car/cdr so root=0 at the very beginning for me), then we get to **gc-loop** (free!=scan) and

```
  (assign old (op vector-ref) (reg new-cars) (reg scan))
```

which is pointless for me because we push value to a indexer. And later this code has no sense:

```
(assign oldcr (op vector-ref) (reg the-cars) (reg old))
```

What do I get wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Let's use tables for this:

At the start:

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| the-cars | p1 | p3 |  |  |  |
| the-cdrs | p2 | p4 |  |  |  |

| index | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| new-cars |  |  |
| new-cdrs |  |  |

After you move the root to the new location (x sign means broken-heart):

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| the-cars | x | p3 |  |  |  |
| the-cdrs | p5 | p4 |  |  |  |

| index | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| new-cars | p1 |  |
| new-cdrs | p2 |  |

So when it runs to `(assign old (op vector-ref) (reg new-cars) (reg scan))`
The scan is currently pointing to p5, so this assigns old to the car in p5, which is p1, which means the `relocate-old-result-in-new` will continue to work on p1.

Inside relocate-old-result-in-new, it checks if p1 has been moved, if not, then it moves the car & cdr of p1 to a new location, which is p6. And set up broken heart signal for p1.
so the state becomes:

| index | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| the-cars | x | x |  |  |  |
| the-cdrs | p5 | p6 |  |  |  |

| index | 5 | 6 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| new-cars | p1 | p3 |
| new-cdrs | p2 | p4 |

Then it moves to update-car label, which updates the car of scan, which is p1, to the current new, which is p6, and then assign the cdr of scan, which is p2, to old, and continue working on that. After p2 has been moved, it moves to update-cdr label, which sets up the cdr of scan, which is p2, to point to a new location, then increase scan, and continue the gc-loop, which will start at p6.

For `(assign oldcr (op vector-ref) (reg the-cars) (reg old))`, it is a way to hold the car & cdr of the object pointed by old, to ease the check for broken heart, the moves... . So if the above makes sense to you, I guess understand oldcr would not be a problem.